# How I can install and configure an existing Laravel Project? (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to install and configure an existing Laravel 4 project.

I tried to do, but when I ran `composer update` or `composer install` a lot of issues appear.

I have the database too (with data) so I ran the migration but doesn't work because the console show me an issue about the "table doesn't exist".

Can anyone tell me the complete process to configure the App?.

I mean, what its first, second and so and so because maybe in some step I made a mistake

Comment: seriously, every app has different dependecncies. No one here can tell you what your specific app needs without looking at it.

Comment: I know that every app is different, but I think every app has a process. I work with Ruby on Rails and no matter what kind of app, exist an standard procedure. 

If the app has particular dependencies that's another thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

To install and configure an existing project, you'd typically

1. Check out its source code/ configure `.env`
2. Run `composer install`
3. Run `php artisan migrate`
4. Check the `README` for specific instructions on installing 3rd party assets, or any additional steps you'd need to take

If the above creates errors, its either because of something in your environment (installing over an old project?) or some problem with the way the Laravel developer created their project.

Comment: Alan, I've been working with Laravel for a (little) while and have run composer install after pulling my project but it fails to install artisan.  I've deployed other apps and never had the issue.  Any thoughts on why it fails installing?

Comment: I don't believe so.  When I run the install in a clean directory on my local everything is good.  The issue only appears when deploying to my AWS instance.  I scped the artisan file to the server and everything appears to be working.  Just a weird issue though it may have something to do with the server setup.  Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 2):

To install and configure an existing project, you'd typically check those things first :

1. You should goto `app/config/database.php` check file and verify username and password.
2. After check in Project Folder `vendor` folder and `composer.json` file exist then remove it (that remove old configuration now we going to fresh configuration).
3. Then after back to command prompt and fire command `composer update` and that download some dependent file download.
4. Now Run `php artisan serve`

that tricks work for me last time when I migrate another host.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos, when using an existing DB you'll need to check the migrations table to see which migrations have run successfully.  Typically when taking over a laravel project setting up a new db and running the migrations against it is a good idea because you never know what hacks were made to the database outside the migration system.  One small change can throw the entire system into a useless state because it's looking for a table or column that doesn't exist or has been modified.  If you run the migrations against a bare db you can also figure out which tables were manually created (which could very well be your issue) outside the system and add them in as necessary.  Cobbling things together after a previous developer is tedious, hopefully there is decent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using Git with `.gitignore`, don't forget to copy `.env` variables in new location too.